# Recovering from MySQL Error 144 via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> 144 - Table 'my table name' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

I don't have any shell terminal to access my table.

How can this be solved using phpMyAdmin?

I have already run this:

```
CHECK TABLE [mytable name];
REPAIR TABLE [mytable name] USE_FRM; 
-- or without FRM. I got no response from this one.
ANAYLZE TABLE [mytable name]
```

Comment: If Repair table is not working then only bet would be to restart the server. if you are on shared hosting ask your provider to restart the Database server.

Comment: You can visit this link to get the answer :- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/how-to-recover-mysql-table-structure-from-frm-files

Comment: Was this an InnoDB table or a MyISAM table that crashed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ANALYZE instead of ANAYLZE?

Answer (score 4):

Try running the command, `'myisamchk -r'`, which is meant to drop the invalid rows in the MySQL table and reconstruct its index file. The utility helps in verifying and repairing the damaged MySQL database tables.

After running `‘myisamchk’` utility, run the ‘Check Table’ command to verify the MyISAM table for errors, if there is any. The syntax for the command is as below:

```
CHECK TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name] ... [option] …
option = {FOR UPGRADE | QUICK | FAST | MEDIUM | EXTENDED |  CHANGED}
```

If the problem is still there, you can repair the corrupt MySQL database table by running the command, 'Repair Table' as below:

```
REPAIR [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name] ... [QUICK] [EXTENDED] [USE_FRM]
```

Comment: You say "drop invalid rows". Does this mean there will be data loss? If so, how to recover without data loss? Should we consider restoring a backup at this point?